# Can i use alfresco as engine for my web java aplication?

Tags: java, web, alfresco

I have a java web project on Glassfish. This project must provide the following functional: edit word file, save it and upload to the database(document repository). Can I use alfresco sdk or api for this functional ? If so, how ?

Answer (score 2):

You can definitely use Alfresco (either Enterprise Edition or Community Edition) as a backend Document Management System for your web application, and for accessing / altering document in the Alfresco repository you can use either CMIS or the RESTful API; but in your particular usecase I would definitely go for CMIS as it guarantees compatibility of your application with other Document repositories such as Sharepoint, Documentum, nuxeos or filenet ... just in case your requirements evolve to need such a transition !

The [platform integrations page](http://docs.alfresco.com/community/concepts/dev-platform-integrations.html) of the Alfresco official documentation does list in detail all you need to know in order to integrate Alfresco with other solutions!

---

And for the record, unless you have some special requirements in your usecase that are not covered OOTB by Alfresco, and that are not that easy (nor intuitive) to develop, I would recommend you to use the OOTB client for Alfresco, the one that is delivered by default within the installer. It does, AIFAIK, cover the requirements you listed thanks to the closed-source free module delivered with: "[Alfresco Office Services](http://docs.alfresco.com/community/concepts/aos-intro.html)" for editing repository document in MS Office directly from a repo action, or the opensource free add-on that gets delivered with the official installer too: "[Google docs integrations](http://docs.alfresco.com/community/concepts/googledocs-intro.html)" for editing documents online in google docs !

Answer (score 1):

The functionality you're describing is called "Edit online", meaning, you don't have to download the file, open it, change it, and upload it back in separate steps - rather online.

http://docs.alfresco.com/5.0/concepts/aos-intro.html